# Is it safe to send username/password in the clear?

Tags: ios, authentication, ssl, oauth

My website is creating an app that extends its functionality - which means that the app doesn't need to follow a strict OAuth process, since we clearly trust ourselves.

We'd like the user of the app to be able to enter their username and password from within the app...which means  we need a way to transport that info to the webserver to validate them.

Assuming we are using SSL, is this a safe idea?

Do we need to take extra steps, and do we need to somehow insure that the request is coming from our app, and not a spoofed app, or something?

Comment: as a courtesy to the user I would never do so.  It's just too easy to encrypt the username/password and send it along prior to transmitting.

Comment: So, the process could be...1. user enters username/pass, 2. my app encrypts for sending, 3. info is sent to server, 4. server somehow validates encrypted data?

Comment: Assuming SSL, the encryption already takes place. Your issue is validating the request itself, to make sure it came from your app.

Comment: yes, using a shared encryption key you can easily encrypt/decrypt the data on both ends.  I guess it depends on the sensitivity of the data, but for a username and password, absolutely.

Comment: You don't need to know the password itself, only that the password entered in the app matches the password on the server. To achieve this, you can store the hashed password on the server and only send the hash over the wire.

Comment: @SedateAlien No no no, a thousand times no. That means that anybody who gets the password database can then log in as any user.

Comment: @Patrick: What are you talking about? If someone gets the database of password hashes, they can log in as any user _on that website_. If the passwords are stored in the clear, they can not only log in as any user on that website, but take advantage of users who reuse the same password everywhere. How is that preferable?

Comment: @SedateAlien, as you say, hashing passwords is good if users re-use their passwords on other sites. This question is more about protecting the connection, this is completely different. Sending the hash itself directly wouldn't help: it would effectively become the password (unless you use something more complex like HTTP Digest with multiple hashes).

Comment: @SedateAlien If someone gets the password hash, normally they can't log in until they crack it which is (theoretically, assuming you pick a slow, strong hash) a time-consuming operation. That's the entire point of sending the password and having the server hash it.

Comment: @Bruno: The question stated that they are using SSL. The connection is protected.

Comment: @Patrick: What advantage is there to sending the password in cleartext over SSL to sending the hash of the password over SSL?

Comment: @SedateAlien, I know that the connection is over SSL and protected. It seems that the OP wasn't quite sure if this was enough. There is no point hashing the password before sending it in this case. Unless the password protocol is designed for this (like HTTP Digest), there is little point in hashing the password before transmission: it's normally hashed when received by the server for it to compare to what was stored. Yes, storing hashes of passwords is a good idea anyway, but the OP seemed more concerned about the difference between access from the browser or from the app.

Comment: @SedateAlien: If you send the password, then if the password hash database is compromised they have to reverse the has before they can log in. If you send the hash, then if the hash database is compromised they can just send the hash back to you and log in immediately as anybody.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, trusting yourselves is not enough. You will have no control of your app, the device on which its used or the network it's connected to once it's in the hands of your users.

A scheme where you would have a common shared key within your app which only your server would be able to decipher (as alluded in comments) could still cause problems, because users who get hold of your application could possibly reverse-engineer it and obtain that key to target other users.

If you're not using Single-Sign On (SSO) for authenticating to your website, but use plain usernames and passwords in a form, transmitting that over an SSL/TLS connection from your application will be no different from doing so from a browser (over HTTPS), provided that the overall configuration is correct. This is already what happens when you post a form from a browser anyway.
By using SSL/TLS as you suggest, you're actually not sending your password in clear (provided it's configured properly).

Checking whether it comes from your application or a spoofed app is a different matter, which is very difficult to protect against in general. If your service is well-designed, it's often not worth it when you already have user authentication anyway. Authenticated users should only be able to perform actions your server allows them to do, whether the request for those actions come from your app or another app controlled by these users (as long as the server verifies they are authenticated correctly). (Spoof apps tend to be more of a problem for the users themselves, if they are tricked into using them, rather than the service itself in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible security threats, any of which you can decide whether or not you want to worry about: http://xkcd.com/538/

But the security's original sin is "password in the clear". At least hash it so that it's not stored in the clear on the server.

Comment: Indeed we are certainly hashing it on the server. I'll check up on that link :)

Comment: The next step then would be to hash it between client and server, in case the website is accessed through an unsecured WiFi: http://xkcd.com/341/